# How does the compiler know what instructions to block when jthread::join is called?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

Take this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std::literals;

void print(std::string msg) {
    while (true) {
        std::cout << msg << '\n';
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(3s);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::jthread t1{ print, "Hello world!" };
    std::jthread t2{ print, "Batman" };

    t1.join();
    std::cout << "Is not printed\n";
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

In this code, both t2 and t1 are executed concurrently, but `"Is not printed"` is never printed. If `join` blocks the current thread until the joined thread finishes, how is the code `t2.join()` ever called, since `t1` should run forever? Isn't the call to `t2.join()` in the main thread, which should be blocked? Does the compiler have special rules that it will only block instructions that are not calls to `std::jthread::join`, like `std::cout << "Is not printed?"`?

EDIT: When I ran this program, I expected only "Hello world" to be printed every 3 seconds, but for some reason it prints Batman every 3 seconds as well. I am confused by this behavior, because I thought the program should block until `t1` finished. I am aware that `t1`, `t2`, and the main thread are different threads. I know that only the main thread should be blocked, in which case "Batman" should be printed. However, the call the start `t2` is in the main thread. Why isn't that instruction blocked, as opposed to `std::cout << "Is not printed"`?

Comment: Why do you suppose that `t2.join()` is ever evaluated?

Comment: @DavisHerring I tested this program, and join is called for both threads while std::cout << "is not printed" is never run.

Comment: How have you figured that `join()` is called?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Batman and Hello world get printed every 3 seconds. If join for the second thread was not called, the program would not print out batman

Comment: Why wouldn't you expect "Batman" to get printed?  You're starting a threat to print that and sleep in an infinite `while`.

Comment: Your program has three threads: `t1`, `t2`, and the main thread. Both `t1` and `t2` run concurrently, and the main thread is blocked on the `t1.join()`. So they will both print. Do you know what `join()` does? I think you misunderstand what `join()` does.

Comment: You're confusing concurrency and parallelism.  In some systems, you would enqueue a task, but it wouldn't make any progress until you finished or blocked every other task.  Threads run independently of one another, not waiting for `join` or anything else (after construction) to start.  On a multi-processor machine, they literally run at the same time.

Comment: "I thought the program should block until `t1` finished": the _main thread_ will block, because it's the one calling `t1.join()`. Both other threads are free to run as much as they want. If you want `t2` to start after `t1` has exited, don't create it before the join.

Comment: The compiler doesn't know. The threading library does, usually with the backing of the operating system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you invoke t1 and t2, on the first two lines of main(), then those threads begin executing immediately. At that moment, 3 functions are running simultaneously in 3 threads: t1, t2, and main().

This is why you see "hello world" and "batman" both being printed. Because those threads are both executing those functions concurrently.

Your main() function is blocked on `t1.join()`. This is waiting for t1 to finish executing. So your main() function never even gets to the "Is not printed" line, as it is still waiting for t1 to finish (and t1 will never finish because you have an infinite loop.)

All `join()` means is "wait here until the thread is done executing."

Comment: Thank you, my misunderstanding was that join starts the thread when it is actually the construction of the thread.